# Swing - Irregular button array layout

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

Is there some way to have a set of `JButton` objects that aren't in a standard 'Grid' shape? I'm specifically looking to make a set of buttons that are different shapes and sizes, like the bottom two rows of the Microsoft Calculator.

Here is an example of what I want the buttons to look like:

[image: Bottom two rows, Microsoft Calculator]

Comment: [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) could easily create that layout.

Comment: Just to avoid the problems with layout adjustments, and concentrate more on application logic, its better to use some third party libraries like http://www.miglayout.com/.

Comment: @K139 In order to avoid problems with the run-time class path and the size of the distributable, **use J2SE layouts!**

Comment: @AndrewThompson Agreed!

Comment: There is also the option of [`GroupLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html), but before I get kicked out of here for mentioning this option, I would just like to--

Answer (score 2):

GridBagLayout is natural choice for requested layout. You can spread buttons evenly, occupy range of cells or even choose size for each particular cell. Here is good [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/AGridBagLayoutExampleweightxweighty.htm).